# Unable to npm install web3 on Windows 10

Tags: web3js, nodejs, visual-studio

I followed every thing on this page :

https://medium.com/@PrateeshNanada/steps-to-install-testrpc-in-windows-10-96989a6cd594

Except step number 5 where my Node.js version is 8.10.0 instead of 8.10.2 which i dont think is a big difference.

I have installed VS 2017 Community Edition , Windows 10 SDK, OpenSSL , npm-gyp.
I have ran the command `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` to install all the latest build tools and still get this error. Help is needed.

### **EDIT**

I have uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and just install Build Tools through the `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` command. A new error appears. How?

```
pm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=No such file or directory
npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No such file or directory
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-12T04_26_35_361Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node-gyp offers several alternatives to install the Visual C++ compiler, but unfortunately VS 2017 is not one of them.

From their [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#option-2).

- Option 1: Install Visual C++ Build Tools using the Default Install option.
- Option 2: Install Visual Studio 2015 and select Common Tools for Visual C++ during setup. This also works with the free Community and Express for Desktop editions.
- Option 3: if you already have Visual Studio 2015 installed and did not install the Common Tools for Visual C++ during setup, you can File -> New -> Project, pick any of the options under Templates -> Other Languages -> Visual C++ then Ok and Visual Studio will offer to install the Common Tools for Visual C++ with a "Install Missing Features" / "You need the Universal Windows App Development Tools to develop Windows app projects." dialog.

Comment: They should really update the compiler. Anyways , edited my question to address your answers. Please have a look.

Comment: @SyedAriff The error is pretty clear "fatal: unable to connect to github.com". From the https://status.github.com/messages it appears github.com is working I'd suggest to try again.

Comment: Nothing changed. Tried 5 times and still the same error occurs. Tried npm install websocket but didn't change anything.

Comment: Issue solved , I voted you as the correct answer cause you managed to eliminated my previous issues. The answer is npm install ethereum/web3.js instead of npm install web3.

Comment: Interesting issue I've tried with `npm install ethereum/web3.js` and `npm install web3` it both works without issues, Windows 7 x64, VC++ 2015 Community Edition, node v8.9.4.