# showing error when doing npm install to install openzeppelin it shows error

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20

when i am trying to install the dependencies using npm install from openzeppelin.it shows error as 
  **Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.**

Comment: Are you on windows? perhaps this helps https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/42429. If you are not then try to follow the instruction on [node-gyp installation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) it requires python 2.7 and will not work with any version of python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has a built-in dialog for changing environment variables (following guide applies to XP classical view): Right-click the icon for your machine (usually located on your Desktop and called “My Computer”) and choose Properties there. Then, open the Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables button.

In short, your path is:

```
My Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced ‣ Environment Variables
```

In this dialog, you can add or modify User and System variables. To change System variables, you need non-restricted access to your machine (i.e. Administrator rights).

Another way of adding variables to your environment is using the set command:

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib

To make this setting permanent, you could add the corresponding command line to your autoexec.bat. msconfig is a graphical interface to this file.

Viewing environment variables can also be done more straight-forward: The command prompt will expand strings wrapped into percent signs automatically:

`echo %PATH%`

[source](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29477)

Comment: Added complete answer.